# Unsure about this differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to find a general solution of the following differential equation:

$x(t)x'(t)e^{x(t)^2} = te^{t^2}, t \in [0,\infty)$

But I'm not sure how to proceed. A solution I came up with was $x(t) = \sqrt{t^2 + \ln |2C|}$ with $t \in [0, \infty)$ and $C \in \mathbb{R}$. However, I'm not sure if this is correct. (I don't think so)

Comment: It looks separable: $xe^{x^2} dx = t e^{t^2} dt$.

Comment: Does that mean you can integrate the left side of the equation in terms of x and the right side of the equation in terms of t?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: Yes, that's what separable means. There are some technicalities, but at the end of the day that's how you solve separable problems.

Comment: Okay, I tried to solve it in this way. But I still get my answer of $x(t) = \sqrt{t^2 + \ln |2C|}$, does this mean it is correct or am I still doing something wrong?

Comment: If you're unsure whether it's right, take the derivative and plug it into the differential equation. (Note that you don't need to keep the $C$ term in that complicated form, you can write it as just $\sqrt{t^2+C}$ instead.)

Comment: I am getting $x = \sqrt{0.5 \ln((e^{t^2})^2 + C)}$

Comment: I am getting $x=\sqrt{\log(e^{t^2}+C)}$.

Answer (score 0):

it is a separable one $$\frac{x'(t)}{\frac{e^{-x(t)^2}}{x(t)}}=e^{t^2}t$$
the solution can be obtained by
$$\int e^{(x(t))^2}\frac{dx(t)}{dt}x(t)dt=\int e^{t^2}tdt$$

Comment: There's a small error, possibly a typo